# React-Redux: Pasando el state a componentes internos

Tags: reactjs, redux

puede parecer que es una pregunta simple pero despues de varios días sigo sin encontrar respuesta.

El caso es que tengo una simple aplicacion que conecto mediante las funciones de Redux. La estructura sería asi:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Y luego en el componente de **App** es donde tengo mis rutas:

```
export class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isLoginPage: PropTypes.bool,
    activeMenu: PropTypes.bool,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div >
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path={ publicPath } component={ Authorization(Timesheet) } />
                <Route path={ routeCodes.LOGIN } component={ Login } />
                <Route path={ routeCodes.SETTINGS } component={ Authorization(Settings) } />
                <Route path='*' component={ NotFound } />
              </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLoginPage: state.login.get('isLoginPage'),
    activeMenu: state.menu.get('activeMenu'),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(App);
```

Mi problema es, que si me creo otro componente y lo meto dentro de uno de esos, por ejemplo, dentro de **Authorization**, ese componente, por cualquier razón, no se conecta.

Un ejemplo de componente que uso sería:

```
export class Menu extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    // from react-redux connect
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.openMenu = this.openMenu.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeMenu: false,
    }
  }

  openMenu() {
    debugger;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Menu2
        <button onClick={this.openMenu}>button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Menu.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLogout: state.menu.get('isLogout'),
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  {
    pure: false,
  }
)(Menu);
```

Si añado el componente  dentro de **Timesheet**, nunca pasa por la función de mapStateToProps, sin embargo si pongo  dentro de **App**, de esta manera:

```
render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Menu />
            <div >
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={ publicPath } component={ Authorization(Timesheet) } />
                    <Route path={ routeCodes.LOGIN } component={ Login } />
                    <Route path={ routeCodes.SETTINGS } component={ Authorization(Settings) } />
                    <Route path='*' component={ NotFound } />
                  </Switch>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
```

Asi funciona perfectamente, esta conectado, y cada vez que se modifica el estado, pasa por la función de mapStateToProps del componente **Menu**.

¿Se os ocurre que puede estar pasando o faltando?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es posible que sea por la manera en que se enganchan los componentes con el <BrowserRouter>, que se pierda de alguna manera la conexión con redux ?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de encerrarlos sino no te lo aceptara ya que (BrowserRouter) es como una propiedad o velo como una configuración, entonces nunca encerraste tu componente

**opción 1**

```
render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div >
                <Menu />
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={ publicPath } component={ Authorization(Timesheet) } />
                    <Route path={ routeCodes.LOGIN } component={ Login } />
                    <Route path={ routeCodes.SETTINGS } component={ Authorization(Settings) } />
                    <Route path='*' component={ NotFound } />
                  </Switch>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

**Opción 2**

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <Route>
                <Menu />
                <div >
                      <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={ publicPath } component={ Authorization(Timesheet) } />
                        <Route path={ routeCodes.LOGIN } component={ Login } />
                        <Route path={ routeCodes.SETTINGS } component={ Authorization(Settings) } />
                        <Route path='*' component={ NotFound } />
                      </Switch>
                </div>
            </Route>
          </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien su pregunta, para empezar, ud. necesita eliminar `export` de en frente de `class App extends Component`, porque lo esta exportando aqui `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);`, y en el futuro por favor incluye sus importaciones asi:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

por si acaso algo va mal ahi, no podemos verlo.
Si esta utilizando las funciones de Redux, debe agregar lo que esta sucediendo en su carpeta de `reducers`. Por ejemplo, si desea implementar autenticación, debes crear un archivo llamado `auth.js` y en el incluir el código siguiente:

```
import { CHANGE_AUTH } from 'actions/types';

export default function(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_AUTH:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

No se olvide del tipo de acción en un archivo `types.js`:`export const CHANGE_AUTH = 'change_auth';`.

El código en la acción llamada `auth.js` dice ponle un inicio de falso al estado donde vas implementar un booleano de `false` utilizando un argumento de función predeterminada que vino con ES6. La idea es desarrollar un botón con una declaración condicional como la siguiente utilizando un método ayudante

```
class App extends Component {
  renderButton() {
    if (this.props.auth) {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => this.props.changeAuth(false)}>Sign Out</button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => this.props.changeAuth(true)}>Sign In</button>
      );
    }
  }
```

Y después implementar el ayudante en un botón en el método `render()` como el siguiente:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderButton()}
        <Route path="/post" component={AgregarMenu} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={MenuList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

O mejor aun es agregar ese ayudante en otro ayudante que formaría parte del "header" del navegador como el siguiente:

```
renderHeader() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/post">Add To Menu</Link>
        </li>
        <li>{this.renderButton()}</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

entonces ese ayudante de `renderHeader()` se puede implementar en el método `render()` así:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderHeader()}
        <Route path="/post" component={AgregarMenu} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={MenuList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

En fin, en este caso se implementa `mapStateToProps` de la siguiente manera:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { auth: state.auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Aquí no estoy solamente devolviendo "logged out" si no cualquiera de los dos según lo que se devuelva de `state.auth`. Y anota de nuevo que estoy haciendo `export default` al fondo del archivo de `App`, así no hace falta usar `export default` al comienzo en la clase de `App`. Anota también que le pase las acciones a la función `connect()`.

Ahora sobre su clase de `Menu` no estoy cien por ciento seguro pero podrá hacer lo siguiente

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Menu extends Component {
  renderMenus() {
    return this.props.menus.map((menu) => {
      return <li key={menu}>{menu}</li>;
    });
  }
```

De nuevo, puede exportar al fondo del archivo, si lo hace así, no necesita utilizar las clave `export default` al comienzo de su clase. Le ofrezco esta implementación porque me imagino un menu siendo como una lista básica como un todo o cualquier otra.

Ese `renderMenus()` ayudante se implementaria en el metodo `render()` asi:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h4>MenuList</h4>
        <ul>
          {this.renderMenus()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { menus: state.menus }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuList);
```

De esta manera, funcionaria todo. Espero que esto lo ayude.